# Why I am getting an error when I am using common expression table in MySQL? ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql

```
with cte as(select h.hacker_id , name , count(challenge_id)
from hackers h , challenges c
where h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id , name ),

select *
from cte;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte as(select *...
this is the error I am getting
Also , I have tried removing the comma after the expression and kept it as well , both cases it is similar error

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: You have a `,` behind the `with cte as (....)` statement (before the second `SELECT`). Is that correct?

Comment: The comma between CTE and main query forces MySQL to search for second CTE... remove this comma.

Comment: I am trying to solve a coding challenge. In this I want to use multiple temporary tables. On the same website , I have solved many challenges with using Common table expression with exact same syntax but in this case it doesn't seem to work. I have removed the comma and kept it , in both cases same error is coming @Progman

Comment: @Akina I did try but no success

Comment: @ParthMaster Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: Share **precise** MySQL version.